# Alternatives to FTP for website file transfer? FTP never works anymore

Tags: ftp

I'm looking for alternative ways that I can transfer files to from websites without FTP or some other work around for my current problems. I have a few sites that I used to be able to transfer up and down batches of files rapidly with FTP but I recently moved to living on campus at my University. I have to use a National University Wifi network to access internet.

The speed is very good but ever since I've never been able to reliably use FTP. I can connect but it's extremely slow and fails 3 out of 4 times, I have difficulty uploading or downloading even a single file. I think the problem is somehow related to the Wifi network I have to use. I have already tried lots with messing with advanced FTP settings for the sites but no results. I can use my cPanel's built in file transfer just fine but it's an awful interface that can't do batches or folders. I really need help to find some solutions so I can start working with websites again.

Comment: How about you nip off-campus? or connect via cellular data?

Comment: More likely a PASV problem due to port blocking by the UNI. You should attempt to configure your FTP client in various FTP modes, try flashfxp, and try different `list` types, and transfer modes. Also, cPanel file manager you can upload ZIPS then uncompress them, which is by far the fastest way and most reliable for your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with your hosting company to see if they can give you SSH access; this will allow you to us SFTP instead.

Most FTP clients (e.g. WinSCP or FileZilla or gFTP) will let you use SFTP in pretty much the same way. You'll even get the benefit of an encrypted connection so your local/campus ISP won't be able to intercept your traffic.

Comment: Plus FTP sends your login credentials as cleartext. Anyone using FTP, telnet, smtp, pop3 or any of those old style plaintext credential exchangers in the current security environment is asking for a good old fashioned packet sniff.